# VueJS validation change locale during runtime

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vee-validate

VueJS app allows changing language during runtime via vue-i18n. This works with all other texts except with validation error messages via vee-validate. It is possible to set language for validation error messages during loading.

How to allow changing vee-validate error messages during runtime?

Current code

```
import et from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/et';
import ru from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/ru';
import VeeValidate, {Validator} from 'vee-validate';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Validator.localize('et', et);

const messages = {
    en: {},
    ru: {}
};

let locale = "et";
Vue.use(VueI18n);
let i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: locale,
    messages
});

let validateConfig = {
    // i18n: i18n,
    locale: locale
};

Vue.use(VeeValidate, validateConfig);
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? Same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `this.$i18n.locale = locale;`